# Fight between A and B and C and D

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

“Fight between A and B and C and D” can mean both?

1. Fight between a team of A and B & a team of C and D”
2. Fight between A and B & fight between C and D

Comment: Yes, the sentence is vague.

Answer (score 1):

Your stated sentence "Fight between A and B and C and D” can mean the same thing as the other two sentences.

To make the meaning clear, you should choose either of the alternatives.

For instance,

> The fight between a team of A and B and a team of C and D....

> The fight between A and B and the fight between C and D....